# How to add custom column in admin grid using block in magento2.2.5?

Tags: adminhtml, grid, magento-2.2.5

How to add custom column in admin grid using block in magento2.2.5. I dont know how 
to implement this task. Could you please help me? please find the below screenshot.
https://prnt.sc/q267fw

Answer (score 0):

You may add it from your `Grid.php` file itself. For example, if the custom column name is `Country`,

```
$this->addColumn(
    'country',
    [
        'header' => __('Country'),
        'index' => 'param_id',  // this is optional parameter (if you want to pass one of the available values in collection) 
        'filter' => false,
        'renderer' => 'YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Column\NewsGridCountryName'
    ]
);
```

Now you have to add the class `NewsGridCountryName.php` which will return the value. For example,

```
namespace YourVendor\YourModule\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Column;
use \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer;

class NewsGridCountryName extends AbstractRenderer
{
    protected $_objectmanager;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
    ) {
        $this->_objectmanager = $objectmanager;
    }

    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        // $row contains the parameters available in the grid collection, like 'param_id'
        $collection = $this->_objectmanager->create('YourVendor\YourModule\Model\ResourceModel\Country\Collection'); // get your own country collection here
        $cell = $collection->getCountryName();
        return $cell;
    }
}
```

Try this way please, let me know if it works.